# How can I make multiple search fields with AJAX Datatables?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables

I have a Datatables table with AJAX:
https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html
Using this class:
https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php

This is my Controller:

```
$whereResult = "";
        if(isset($_POST['provider_id'])) {
            $whereResult.= "provider = ".$_POST['provider_id']['value'];
        }

        $table = 'providers_catalog';
        $primaryKey = 'id';
        $columns = array(
            array( 'db' => 'product_id', 'dt' => 0 ),
            array( 'db' => 'provider',   'dt' => 1 ),
            array( 'db' => 'sku',     'dt' => 2 ),
            array( 'db' => 'description',     'dt' => 3 )
        );

        echo json_encode(
            SSP::complex( $_GET, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $whereResult, $whereAll = null )
        );
```

And in my view I try to make another AJAX call, but it doesn't recharge the table:

```
$('#provider_id').change(function () {
                            var txt = {value: $(this).val(), column: "" + $(this).attr('id') + "" };
                            if(txt != '') {
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: "Catalog/paginate",
                                    method:"post",
                                    data:{provider_id:txt},
                                    dataType:"text",
                                    success:function(data) {

                                    },error:function () {
                                        alert("Error");
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
```

The default AJAX Datatables have the input Search that find in any column and then recharge the table, but is integrated with all the components. How can I make custom search fields for each column of my DB?

Answer (score 1):

solved with this plugin:
https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html
Thanks everybody

Comment: This isn't a plugin, it's a native DataTables feature.

Answer (score 0):

Debug Your code like this

Controller:

```
<?php echo "reached controller";  ?>
```

View:

```
 $.ajax({       
                url: "controller_location",
                method:"POST",
                data:({provider_id:txt}),
                success:function(data) {
                     alert("Success : "+data);
                },
                error:function () {
                    alert("Error : "+data);
                }
            });
```

Hope this helps :)